# How does strace work?

Tags: system-calls, strace

It can trace all system calls used.

But what differs a sys_call from a normal call??

Answer (score 48):

As Matthew said, strace uses the [ptrace(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) system call to work its magic. ptrace is used to implement debuggers and other tools which need to inspect what another program is doing. Essentially, strace will call ptrace and attach to a target process.

Whenever the target process makes a system call, it will stop, and strace will be notified. strace will then inspect the registers and stack of the target process (also using ptrace) to determine what system call was being made (each call has a unique number, passed in a register) and what the arguments were. strace then resumes the process. When it returns from the system call, it is stopped, and strace is notified again, so it can inspect the return value. strace prints some information for the user each time this happens.

In response to your second question, a system call is different from a normal function call in that a system call is implemented in the kernel, while a regular function is implemented in userspace. That's a whole separate can of worms though.

Comment: If the parameter of a syscall(e.g. read) is a pointer, how does the strace get the content of that pointer?

Answer (score 16):

I wrote a blog post [about how strace works](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/02/29/how-does-strace-work/) and an even longer blog post [about how syscalls work](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/).

`strace` works by using the `ptrace` system call which causes the kernel to halt the program being traced each time it enters or exits the kernel via a system call. The tracing program (in this case `strace`) can then inspect the state of the program by using `ptrace`.

`strace` gets the arguments to each system call depending on how that system works. On x86-64 systems, arguments to system calls are passed in CPU registers. In this case, `strace` can call `ptrace` with the `PTRACE_GETREGS` argument to get a copy of the register values and print them.

Comment: Hey, would love to read about those articles, but it seems the website is not working properly. **403 ERROR - The request could not be satisfied.**
Is there some login procedure that needed to be done ?

Comment: Quick update, the link must be https://, lol

Answer (score 0):

Syscalls are the interface between user and kernel space.  See [man 2 syscalls](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) or [syscalls.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/syscalls.h) for the list.

They should not be confused with standard C library functions, such as `printf`.  These often end up calling a syscall, but not necessarily.  Further, a user space program can call a syscall directly with the [syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscall) function.

Comment: But how does recognize syscalls **programatically**??

Comment: The bottom line is that it uses [`ptrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace).  You can read [the source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/external/strace/strace.c&q=strace.c&sa=N&cd=1&ct=ri) (that's the Android version) for the exact details.

Comment: How does it intercept arguments?