# override libc open() library function

Tags: linux, gcc, overriding, ld, glibc

I have same overridden open() which is provided by **glibc** in my library & I have set `LD_PRELOAD` with my library first, so when the process calls `open()`, the open which is defined in my library gets called.

THE PROBLEM:- There are several other functions within **glibc** which calls open() once such example is `getpt()`, when `getpt()` calls `open()`, the `open()` which is defined in **glibc** gets called, how would I make `getpt()` to invoke the `open()` which is defined in my library().

Constraints: - I dont have the option of compiling glibc.

Answer (score 2):

As correctly stated by tmcguire, the call from `posix_openpt` to `__open` is a call to *internal* symbol, and can not be interposed.

Effectively, `glibc` developers consider this call an implementation detail, that you have no business of changing.

> I am looking at compile time solution

You can't have it.

> than run time solution cause run time solution will have performance impact.

Runtime solution need not have any performance impact (besides the overhead of calling your `open` instead of `glibc`s).

I only know of one way for a library to interpose `glibc` internal calls: runtime patching. The idea is to

- find the address of `libc.so.6` `open` (which is an alias for `__open`),
- locate the boundaries of `glibc` `.text` section at runtime
- scan it for `CALL __open` instructions
- for any such instruction

  - `mprotect` the page it's on to be writable
  - compute a new instruction that is `CALL my_open` and patch it "on top" of the original instruction
  - `mprotect` the page back to read and execute

This is ugly, but it works fine for i*86 (32-bit) Linux, where a `CALL` can "reach" any other instruction within the 4GB address space. It doesn't work for x86_64, where a `CALL` is still limited to +/- 2GB, but the distance from your library to `glibc` could be more than that.

In that case, you need to find a suitable trampoline within `libc.so.6` to which you can redirect the original `CALL`, and into which you could place a register-indirect `JMP` to your final destination. Fortunately, `libc.so.6` usually has multiple suitably-sized unused `NOP` regions due to function alignment.

Comment: ok, doing this hacking in a production based environment is not good & definitely as you put it, it is ugly.

Comment: @user3465381 FWIW, using `LD_PRELOAD` to interpose `open` is only slightly less ugly, and arguably you shouldn't do that in production either.

Comment: ok, I am providing a library which can be used by both inhouse applications & also third party apps. I dont have the option of editing the third party code. dlopen is also not an option for the same reason that third party code cant be edited. Given these limitations how would you make third party apps call open function defined in your library.? isnt this the exact use case of LD_PRELOAD.?

Comment: I like the "implementation detail" bit, though as you said the patching stuff is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it at compile time simply by defining the getpt() function within my library.

This solution is incomplete cause there could be other functions within glibc [other than getpt()]  which could call open, then open call within glibc will be called.

I can live with this solution for now, but I would need to fix it completely in future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with LD_PRELOAD.

If you look at the disassembly of libc (using e.g. `objdump --disassemble /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep -A20 "<getpt>:"`, you can see that `getpt()` calls `__open()`, which is an alias to `open()`.

```
000000000011e9d0 <posix_openpt>:
  11e9d0:       53                      push   %rbx
  [...]
  11e9ee:       e8 dd d9 fb ff          callq  dc3d0 <__open>
```

However, that call to __open is a PC-relative call that does not go through the PLT - meaning that you can **not** interpose the symbol with LD_PRELOAD, since all calls within libc will not use the PLT. This is probably because libc was linked with `-BSymbolic`.

The only option left is to do what *strace* does, and use **ptrace** to attach to the process. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494316/how-does-strace-work) on how that works.

Comment: while **ptrace** is a good option, but to use ptrace you would need a parent & child relation which would not be acceptable cause I am providing a library, if I have to do it using **ptrace** then I would have to fork & then do a trace on the child. I dont think I can have this solution

Comment: If you can't use ptrace, then I don't see a way to intercept calls to open(), short of dynamic runtime instrumentation like with Intel's PIN library.

Comment: hmm ok, lets see if anyone else has ideas, I am looking at **compile** time solution than run time solution cause run time solution will have **performance** impact.